# In iOS how do I implement sliding a view within another view with momentum?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, gesture

I know how to recognize a **swipe gesture** but I don't know how to make it cause the view it's on to slide left or right with momentum. By **'momentum'** I mean so it keeps sliding for a while after the gesture ends and comes to a stop gradually. I can move the view with a pan gesture but the view is very long and I need to move it further and faster than a pan action. Does the view have to be inside a `UIScrollView`? The pan action works without being in a `scrollView`.

EDIT: A couple comments asked what I want to do. I'm working on an app that receives heart rate data from a sensor via Bluetooth Low Energy and displays it in various ways. So I have a few small UIViews on the screen that each contain a plot of the data. The plots are made just using drawRect and transforms (getting the coordinate labels positioned right was the hardest part so far). One UIView has beats-per-minute (bpm) vs. time, and another has a histogram of bpm values, and I may add more. The bpm vs. time plot allows for two hours of data at one value per second so it's 7200 points wide. I might make it wider. As each new value arrives it is put at the right end. After the plot grows to fill the whole width of the UIView the plot starts moving one point to the left as each new value is added, so the newest data is always visible. A few anomalies are marked when they occur, such as premature beats and missed beats, and those marks stay on the plot and move along with it. The need for swipe and scroll arise because I want the user to be able to swipe back through the data to see the values that went off the screen. I also need to be able to pan (or swipe) up and down in case the range of values didn't fit on the screen after my attempts to fit the vertical scale to the actual data values. So that's what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll go back to trying a scrollview. I think I didn't get it to work because I couldn't figure out where the swipeGesture goes and how to make it cause scrolling.

Comment: This seems like an ideal case for a scroll view. Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to use it?

Comment: Indeed. Let us know what you appear to dislike about `UIScrollView`, which does exactly what you want and requires the tiniest amount of code to use and we can advise on how to do things differently. There's no point reimplementing what the OS already does.

Comment: To the people saying use a scroll view - how would you for example have a large background image A with a smaller image on top of it, then scroll image A relative to image B with image B remaining stationary. Wont A and B scroll  together if you use a scroll view?

Comment: @Sausages:I would place the background image behind the scroll view (not inside the scroll view) and make the scroll view background transparent.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to avoid a scroll view. I first tried a scroll view and didn't get it to work then tried a pan gesture in a plain UIView and it seemed so simple. Based on the comments and answers here I guess I need to go back to a scroll view and make it work. See my edit to the original question for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I have used for the user dragging up/down a view within another view which  is using a gesture recognizer on the view and has momentum to continue after the user lifts their finger.

Just make the necessary changes to adapt it to your view's starting/finishing position and if your scrolling vertically or horizontally etc.

It is NOT using a scroll view. The momentum is achieved using UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut, you can experiment with the other animation curves to see which you like, but this one does as you describe in your posting "keeps sliding for a while after the gesture ends and comes to a stop gradually."

```
- (IBAction)handleVerticalSwipe:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.pulldownViewStartPosition = self.pulldownView.frame.origin.y;
    }
    else
    {
        int maxYPosition = 527; // Calculate at run time

        CGRect targetFrame = self.pulldownView.frame;
        CGFloat newYPos = 0;
        if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        {
            // translationInView: returns a CGPoint which is not the position of the touch but the amount representing
            // the total translation over time.
            // The x and y values report the total translation over time. They are not delta values from the last time that
            // the translation was reported. Therefore the translation value should be applied to the state of the view when
            // the gesture is first recognized and should not be concatenated to the value each time the handler is called.

            CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView: [self.view superview]];

            newYPos = self.pulldownViewStartPosition + translation.y;

            if (newYPos > maxYPosition)
            {
                newYPos = maxYPosition;
            }
            if (newYPos < self.pullDownDefaultPosition)
            {
                newYPos = self.pullDownDefaultPosition;
            }

            targetFrame.origin.y = newYPos;
            self.pulldownView.frame = targetFrame;
        }
        else if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) // User has lifted finger after swipe
        {
            // Gets the velocity of the gesture so it can be determined if the pulldown
            // should extend or retract
            CGFloat yVectorVelocity = [sender velocityInView: [self.view superview]].y;

            if (yVectorVelocity < 0)
            {
                newYPos = self.pullDownDefaultPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                newYPos = maxYPosition;
            }
            targetFrame.origin.y = newYPos;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:kPulldownDefaultAnimationDuration delay:0
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 self.pulldownView.frame = targetFrame;
                             }
                             completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it certainly sounds like a UIScrollView is exactly what you're looking for.  I'm not sure if you can actually disable scrolling with "momentum," but you'll find it behaves just the way you need it to.

Rather than nesting a UIView inside of a UIScrollView, you may find that the UIScrollView does what you need it to do without nesting other UIViews inside of it unnecessarily.  I don't have the reputation to comment, but I wanted to ask about the specific problems you're experiencing, or what you're trying to render "scrollably"...?